# How to use Average where there is text and numbers in the same cell?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a large amount of data which has been captured with a number and unit of measurement in the same cell e.g 65kg

I would like to average the data but keep getting #NAME errors or #value on the formulas I have tried

I have tried using several formula in similar questions with cut and paste and changing the range for the data.

I don't understand the formula well enough to understand the error and correct.

Comment: Do your numbers have a specific format(65kg, 65 kg, 65 - kg)?

Comment: Not enough data! There are too many ways to store strings containing numbers in Excel. Unless you tell us the *specific* formats in your data there is no way anyone will find a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to use VBA, you can try using following code

```
strTest = "65kg" '<---this will be value from cell
strLen = Len(strTest)

' loop for all the characters in string
for i = 1 to strLen
   strNew = left(strTest,i)
   if(ISNUMERIC(strNew)) then
      strNumber = strNew
   else
      exit for
   end if
next

msgbox strNumber
```